# Aspose.Words convert to html (only body content)

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I can create word file and convert HTML with aspose.words API. How do I get the BODY content in HTML with the API (withou html,head,body tag/ only body content). I will use this to show the output in the WYSIWYG editors (summernote) application.

Note: I am developing the application with .net Framework (C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "inputdocx.docx");
var options = new Aspose.Words.Saving.HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Html)
{
ImageSavingCallback = new HandleImageSaving(),
}; 
String html = doc.FirstSection.Body.ToString(options);
```

Comment: Aspose Froum Answer: https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-words-convert-to-html-only-body-content/211630

Comment: @EkremKangal You should note that input document can contain more than one section. In this case the provided code will return HTML only of the first one. To process all sections you should loop through them and combine the resulting html strings.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Aspose.Words saves html in Xhtml format, so you can safely load it into XmlDocument and get bydy tag’s content. For example see the following code.

```cs
// Create a simple document for testing.
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder();
builder.Writeln("Hello world!!!");
// For testing purposes insert an image.
builder.InsertImage(@"https://cms.admin.containerize.com/templates/aspose/App_Themes/V3/images/aspose-logo.png");

// Additional options can be specified in the corresponding save options.
HtmlSaveOptions opt = new HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Html);
// For example, output images in the HTML as base64 string (summernote supports base64)
opt.ExportImagesAsBase64 = true;

// Save the document to MemoryStream.
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    builder.Document.Save(ms, opt);

    // Move the stream position ot the beginning and load the resulting HTML into Xml document.
    ms.Position = 0;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(ms);

    // Find body tag.
    XmlNode body = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//body");

    // Get inner xml of the body.
    Console.WriteLine(body.InnerXml);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.

Comment: Thanks. Does the Aspose.Words API I am trying to learn have such a function or feature?

Comment: @EkremKangal The code I provided uses Aspose.Words to convert document to HTML and XmlDocument to parse the resulting HTML in order to get only body's content as you asked in the original post.